# Visual Studio debugger acting weird

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, mstest

IN VS 2017, when debugging a unit test I encountered a weird issue with the debugger. Can someone let me know why the following is happening.

```
public string TestingPurposesMethod(string name)
{
    string returnVal = null;

    if (name != null)
    {
        if (name == "Kim")
        {
            returnVal = "KimReturn";
        }
        else if (name == "James")
        {
            returnVal = "JamesReturn";
        }
        else if (name == "Wonder")
        {
            returnVal = "WonderReturn";
        }
        else
        {
            returnVal = "None of these";
        }

        return returnVal;
    }

    return null;
}
```

When debugging this method from a unit test while passing 'James' as the parameter, is returning "JamesReturn" as exptected in the unit test.

stepping through each line or code reveals that the cursor or control is checking every condition in the if, else if, else chain, and also assigning values to returnVal.

EDIT:

Look at this screenshot below, the value in `name' is "James" but the debugger goes inside the if statement for "Kim" interestingly though OzCode extension clearly shows that expression evaluation has failed(Red line on line 150).

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Hi Phani, what the weird do you mean? The return value in your project should be JamesReturn, do you mean when debugging you have different value?

Comment: I test your code in MsTest Test Project(.net core), and call the TestingPurposesMethod in my TestMethod, but everything works well. And when debugging, if the input name is James, the debugger will check name == "James", then return returnVal but won't check name == "Wonder". Please updated the vs to 15.9.13 to check if it helps.

Comment: That's normal, if you are doing it right.  A unit test should test the optimized Release build of this code, as it will run on the user's machine.  Sounds like you are doing it right.  There is an option that can suppress the optimization, Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick the "Suppress JIT optimization" checkbox.  But surely best to keep doing it right.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I meant that, when I debug and step through each line returnVal is first being assigned "KimReturn" eventhough name is not equal to "Kim", then it assigns "JamesReturn", then it assigns "WonderReturn" and finally assigns "None of these", but when the control goes back to the unit test after the method execution I see "JamesReturn" as the final response which is the correct one. Why is cursor/control going through every possible execution path eventhough it doesnt satisfy the condition. I have a strong feeling it has got something to do with .net core version/visual studio?

Comment: I would expect it check against "Kim" then jump to checking against "James" assign "JamesReturn" to `returnVal` and jump to `return returnVal`

Comment: Updated the question with screenshot of the behavior I am seeing in VS.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT ^

Comment: @Phani Hi friend, any update for this issue? Please let me know if it has been solved or not :(

Answer (score 0):

When you choose `Debug Selected Tests` in `Test Explorer`, which mode are you in? `Debug mode` or `Release Mode`? I've reproduced similar issue with `Optimize code setting`:
[image]

**To resolve this issue:**

1.Like Hans said, it has something to do with Suppress JIT Optimization, so of course we can Go Debug=>Options and check it, then this issue went away.(Not recommended since it will remove the advantage of Optimized Release...)

2.And by default, the option is unchecked. Actually we don't suggest you make it enabled all the time. Please right-click the Project in Solution Explorer=>Properties to get this page:

[image]

By default for Debug mode, optimize code is unchecked and for release mode, optimize code in checked. So there is possibility that you're in `release mode` to `debug the tests` or you're in `debug mode` but with the `Optimize Code` checked!

So my suggestion is Debug the tests in debug mode after making sure the Optimize Code for debug is unchecked. Then this issue goes away.

And only when #2 not helps, you can try checking the `Suppress JIT Optimization...`(Not recommended)

Hope all above helps:)